# Is there a way to edit the “syslinux.cfg” file to clear the screen then load the kernel with Unetbootin?

Tags: boot, usb, unetbootin

I'm developing an OS and for now I'm using `UNetbootin` to load it from a USB. I only have one option on the menu (boot) so I don't really need the menu to exist. I can set the menu timeout to nothing so I don't have to wait or press enter but the menu still shows up at the lop of the screen when it's loading the kernel.

In short:

##### Is there a way to edit the `syslinux.cfg` file to clear the screen then load the kernel?

Answer (score 1):

According to this info from the [ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org) you just need to comment all the UI related lines(UI menu.c32, etc):

> #### [4.3 Auto boot](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/syslinux#Auto_boot)
>
> If you do not want to see the Syslinux menu at all, use the [#Boot prompt](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/syslinux#Boot_prompt), and set `PROMPT` to `0` and comment out any `UI` menu entries. Setting the `TIMEOUT` variable to `0` might also be a good idea. Make sure there is a `DEFAULT` set in your `syslinux.cfg`. Holding either <kbd>Shift</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd>, or setting either <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> or <kbd>Scroll Lock</kbd>, during boot will allow for options other than default to be used. See the [upstream wiki](https://wiki.syslinux.org/wiki/index.php/Directives/special_keys) for additional alternatives.